# create-react-app creates app with vulnerabilities, audit fix adds more

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I'm trying to create a new react app, I've used

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

to create it, and right from start it tells me that it has vulnerabilities, I run

```
npm audit fix --force
```

and it just adds 100 more, run `fix` again, and it's back to the beginning and so on in a loop.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11174. `npm audit fix --force` is ~never the right thing to do.

Comment: ok, I suppose I just need to ignore those warnings, as long as I don't run audit, it works

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time CRA (create-react-app) is NOT the recommended way to create a react app. ViteJs is. take a look at these 2 links

- https://vitejs.dev/guide/#trying-vite-online - you can see how a react app with Vite is scaffolded

This is the code you can download to start your app

- IF you want TypeScript https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/packages/create-vite/template-react-ts
- IF you DON'T want TypeScript https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/packages/create-vite/template-react